# Align Sidebar (Which is Placed After Content) to the Left

Tags: html, css, layout, sidebar

Basically, I have a layout like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"> HEADER </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="table"><div id="tablerow">
        <div id="content"> MAIN CONTENT </div>   
        <div id="sidebar"> SIDEBAR </div>
        </div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's a bit different in the live website, but basically it's structured like that. The problem is, I want to align sidebar to the left-side, not to the right-side (currently it's on the right).

I'm placing the sidebar after the content, because the content needs to be loaded first, then the sidebar next.

I tried this CSS:

```
#body { overflow:auto; }
#table {display:table;}
#tablerow {display:table-row;}
#sidebar { float:left; width:150px; display:table-cell;margin-right:5px; }
#content { float:right; display:table-cell; }
```

It works nicely in the demo (jsfiddle.net), but it doesn't work at all in the actual website.

Instead, what happened is the sidebar is aligned to the bottom left (after the content). I suppose this is because both the content and the sidebar has `<table>`s, but I'm not sure... I can't remove the `<table>` because those are needed for certain reasons.

Also, if anyone is wondering what is the use of `<div id="table"><div id="tablerow">`, it is used for a certain javascript on the website.

Can anybody help? Pardon my poor English..

Here is the live website if anyone needs to see: http://bleachindonesia.com/forum/ (the HTMLs are messy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
```

remove

```
display: table;
```

From

```
<div style="display: table-row;">
```

remove

```
display: table-row;
```

To

```
<div id="content" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 10px; float: right; display: table-cell;">
```

Give a width, such as

```
width: 900px;
```

Now your

```
<div class="lside" id="sidemenu" style="width: 20%; margin-right: 5px; display: table-cell;">
```

is on the left side.

Comment: Have tried that, but it doesn't work... the sidebar moved to the bottom instead, even after I add `float:left;` on the `<div class="lside" id="sidemenu" ... >`

Comment: Ah I see now--I guess it's because of my resolution screen! Great! Now the sidebar is on the left 

...But there's another problem... that makes the "Show/Hide Sidemenu" javascript won't work (the little "X" thing on the right), because the content width is already set. How to fix this?

Comment: @deathlock: Seems to work for me. When you click on the "X", the sidebar gets hidden. I am using IE9 on windows 7. What are you using?

Comment: Sorry, didn't explain what I meant... I mean, yes, the sidebar gets hidden, but the content won't get wider/won't fill the empty space... if you see the live website, currently the content will get wider if the sidebar get hidden. Anyway, I'm using Google Chrome 10 and Firefox 3.5 on Windows XP..

Comment: Ah. Please locate the JS that handles that. You can add width: 100% for the div#content on the mouseclick event in there. In this way when the pages loads, the width of the div#content is fixed such as 900px or any other that suits your layout. However when the user presses the "X" the width is changed to 100% dynamically. Dont forget to mark the answer as "accepted" if your are satisfied. If not, post a new question with the Javascript tag.

Comment: Thanks @jawad. I tried using the `$('#content').css("width","100%");` (it's jQuery) but it won't get the result I wanted, there's no animation at all. I started a new question, perhaps you can take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568986/set-contents-width-to-100-when-sidebar-is-hidden Thank you again!