# Set Content's Width to 100% when Sidebar is Hidden?

Tags: jquery, css, layout, sidebar

Beforehand, pardon me for my poor English.

Ok so here's a live site I have: http://bleachindonesia.com/forum/

If you notice the little X on the left, it is a toggle to show/hide sidebar. The jQuery is working fine. The only problem is that the content's width won't get wider (to 100%) / won't fill the empty space when I hide the sidebar (the sidebar left an empty space when hidden).

I need the content's width to be 100% when the sidebar is hidden, but retaining its smooth animation. Perhaps like the one in the [vBulletin forum](https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/).

Here is the jQuery btw:

```
//<!--
if($.cookie("sidebarpost") == undefined) {
    $.cookie("sidebarpost", "expanded");
}
var state = $.cookie("sidebarpost");
if(state == "collapsed") {
    $('.lside').hide();
            $('.lclose').hide();
            $('.lopen').show();
}

if($.cookie("sidebarpost") == "expanded") {
    $("#left-side").toggle(function(){
      $.cookie("sidebarpost", "collapsed");
      $('.lopen,.lclose').toggle();
      $('.lside').fadeOut().delay(1000);
      $('#content').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 2000);
    },function(){
      $.cookie("sidebarpost", "expanded");
      $('.lopen,.lclose').toggle();
      $('#content').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 2000).delay(1000);
      $('.lside').fadeIn();
    });
} else {
    $("#left-side").toggle(function(){
      $.cookie("sidebarpost", "expanded");
      $('.lopen,.lclose').toggle();
      $('#content').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 2000).delay(1000);
      $('.lside').fadeIn();
    },function(){
      $.cookie("sidebarpost", "collapsed");
      $('.lopen,.lclose').toggle();
      $('.lside').fadeOut().delay(1000);
      $('#content').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 2000);
    });
}
//-->
```

I know it's kind of bloated, perhaps if there is a way to minimize it, would be very helpful. Can anybody help?

Comment: why not just change the #content width to 100% when it's hidden?

Comment: I did try that, but that doesn't look too good; there's no smooth sliding animation in it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just adjust the `content` width as part of your toggle functions. Something like:

```
$('.lside').fadeOut(400, function(){$('#content').width("98%")});

$('.lside').fadeIn(400, function(){$('#content').width("76%")});
```

Comment: Great! But the content doesn't seem to slide smoothly, I mean like the one in vBulletin here... https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/ Is it possible to make it like that?

Answer (score 0):

In the example what you have given they are doing margin-right:290px for the content area while showing sidebar and width of sidebar as 270px, and while hiding they are making margin-right:0px; and width as 0px;

use [jquery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate the margin-right of content and width of sidebar

Comment: hmm, I realize the jQuery code I'm giving is problematic, so it doesn't give the result I desire. But if you could, perhaps you may look at the live website and the example I wanted...

Comment: Your livesite is not opening for me

Comment: Which one? http://bleachindonesia.com/forum/ or https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/ ? Both should be available, at least for me...